# What does information_schema.TABLES.DATA_FREE mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am not entirely sure what information_schema.TABLES.DATA_FREE means in MySQL.

Can someone please help me understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: For an InnoDB table, it shows the number of bytes in space that is not currently being used in the table

Answer (score 14):

DATA_FREE- The number of allocated but unused bytes.
It is the size of the database files compared to the data stored in the database files. PHPMyAdmin shows this information as 'Overhead in tables'.

However for InnoDB this is important- "InnoDB tables report the free space of the tablespace to which the table belongs. For a table located in the shared tablespace, this is the free space of the shared tablespace.".  So with a typical InnoDB setup ('innondb_file_per_table' is not set) you will get the free space for all tables and not for a single table.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html

Answer (score 10):

According to MySQL's information on [MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html):

> The DATA_FREE column shows the free space in bytes for InnoDB tables

For earlier versions like [5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html):

> The DATA_FREE column shows the free space in bytes for InnoDB tables.
>
> For MySQL Cluster, DATA_FREE shows the space allocated on disk for,
>   but not used by, a Disk Data table or fragment on disk. (In-memory
>   data resource usage is reported by the DATA_LENGTH column.)

Answer (score 1):

With innodb_file_per_table=OFF all InnoDB tables are stored in the same tablespace.
DATA_FREE (the number of allocated but unused bytes) is reported for that single tablespace.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-file-space.html:

"When you ask for available free space in the tablespace by issuing a SHOW TABLE STATUS 
statement, InnoDB reports the extents that are definitely free in the tablespace. InnoDB 
always reserves some extents for cleanup and other internal purposes; these reserved
extents are not included in the free space."

So, for InnoDB tables free space in tablespace is reported, and as all your tables share
the same tablespace, the same value is the result.