# RDS mysql database storage space available is less than the instance allocation

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My available storage doesn't seem to match up with the Instance storage size in RDS.

When I run:

```
    SELECT table_schema "database_name", 
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 
1024 "Database Size in MB", 
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

I get:

```
| database_name      | Data Base Size in MB | Free Space in MB |
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| fx                 |        6787.34375000 |    3239.00000000 |
| information_schema |           0.21875000 |       0.00000000 |
| mysql              |          10.04687500 |       0.00000000 |
| performance_schema |           0.00000000 |       0.00000000 |
```

[image: RDS monitoring also showing a lower level than expected]

So total available space is about 10Gb.

But the storage I have provisioned in RDS for this database instance is **29Gb** (3 times more than the space I actually have).

This is after I've cleared the slow query log and general log.

Can someone clarify the discrepancy here? At the moment I'm risking running out of space.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding `data_free`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9731853/1032785

Comment: Also, RDS supports growing EBS storage without downtime

Comment: @jordanm The RDS monitoring "Free space / Mb" matches the numbers I get from that query. The key point is I've paid for an instance with 29Gb storage and looking at this I'm only getting a third of that - what am I missing - is it somehow not covering 'dark' storage such as indexes?

Comment: I have gone through [This page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-storage-optimization/) and implemented all the actions, even copied the big tables (and ones that have a lot of deleted) into new tables then deleted the originals, but still I get a massive discrepancy. Total Database size is 10Gb, Allocated storage is 30, but earlier this week I ran out, got a storage-full error and my database stopped accepting data. (Yes I have log reporting for this).

I'm at a complete loss why this database seems to be using 3* the allocated storage it should need.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the general error log filling up - I had some batch delete jobs that could potentially run thousands of times daily, which was causing this to get big fast. Switching this off and purging it stopped the storage space continuously dropping. Hope this helps someone in future (Probably just me again).

This is also probably the best write up of options to try:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-storage-rds-mysql-mariadb/