# After ALTER TABLE （Optimize） in Mysql , data_free didn't go to zero

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, alter-table

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAePe.png)

i tried Optimize using ALTER TABEL in mysql, but it did't to go 0
why?..
somebody teach me plz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does information\_schema.TABLES.DATA\_FREE mean in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731853/what-does-information-schema-tables-data-free-mean-in-mysql)

Comment: Don't bother optimizing InnoDB tables; it is not worth the effort.  The non-zero "free" space is kept around to make it faster to add more data.